# Ionic2 Input keyboard

Tags: ionic2

Right now, the problem is that on my log in page, it is non-scrollable and when i click on the ion-input (eg key in username/password), the keyboard shows up and focuses on the input.

Problem is when i close the keyboard, the content doesn't scrolls down to the original display and I am now able to scroll the content, which means the height of the content has increased.

So question is how do I return to the original height of the content after the keyboard closes?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?